# Expanded/ Animated list in Xamarin Forms (MVVM)

Tags: xamarin

Can this animated drop-down list be done in Xamarin? If so, how to do it?

https://dribbble.com/shots/2340386-Shopping-List

Comment: Please state if you want Xamarin.Forms, Xamarin.iOS or Xamarin.Android. They are completely different beasts and the answer will vary between the 3.

Comment: You can have animated drop downs check this http://www.redbitdev.com/cross-platform-animations-using-xamarin-forms/, but you can not call has drop downs, in mobile world theirs stranded way of displaying drop downs...

Answer (score 0):

Here is link with tutorial: 
https://trailheadtechnology.com/xamarin-forms-fancy-animations/

```
//collapse
MyContent.LayoutTo(new Rectangle(MyContent.Bounds.X, MyContent.Bounds.Y, MyContent.Bounds.Width, 0), 500, Easing.CubicIn)
//expand
MyContent.LayoutTo(new Rectangle(MyContent.Bounds.X, MyContent.Bounds.Y, MyContent.Bounds.Width, 300), 500, Easing.CubicOut)
```